# messenger is not working in elementary os Freya

Tags: applications, internet

I have downloaded and installed the messenger `64 bit deb`  from this [website](https://messengerfordesktop.com/) But it doesn't work, I got the following screen.  [image: screens] This is the error I got in the `Dev tools` of the app.[image] Can anyone help me to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that app is a little bit outdated, did you try [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/), is a multi protocol web chat client and it has FB messenger

Comment: is it a third party app, if so what about the security?

Comment: the messenger app that you posted is also a third party app, so i think is the same problem. I know is bad but i really don't mind to much about it xD